# MVC Partial Views, GET and routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Good Day, 
This is my first question, so please be kind. I have just made the move from forms to mvc. 
I have made the following route (below). I constructed a partial view that also contains 2 other partial views (as seen below). 
When submitted the url will be something like **'Find/Index?Region=3&Interest=1'**

1. What is the best way to create a friendly url matching the route defined 
   **'Find/Index/In-Wales-3/Sport-1'**? I could post and then redirect, but I thought this maybe inefficient. A better approach maybe to use jquery?
2. Please also indicate if the design used is correct or if it could be improved upon? The reason for separating the views, is because they are used on multiple views.

Thanks in advance!

### Route Config

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Find",
url: "{controller}/{action}/In-{region}-{rid}/{interest}-{iid}",
defaults: new { controller = "Find", action = "Index", region = UrlParameter.Optional,
                            rid = UrlParameter.Optional,
                            interest = UrlParameter.Optional,
                            iid = UrlParameter.Optional
            });
```

### Partial View That Is Rendered On Master Page

```
@model SimpleFriendFinderModel
    <h1>Find</h1>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Find", FormMethod.Get))
        {
            @Html.Partial("_RegionDropDown", @Model.Regions)
            @Html.Partial("_InterestDropDown", @Model.Interests)
            <div>
                &nbsp;
                <button>SEARCH</button>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

### Region Partial View

```
@model IEnumerable<Region>

<select id="Region" name="Region">
<option>REGION</option>
    @{ foreach(var item in Model) {
        <option value="@item.RegionID">@item.RegionName</option>
    }
}
</select>
```

The other partial view is a replica of Region but obviously a different model.

Comment: As for your first question, it is actually a nice one. When you open the page, without the post, is the URL in the `Find/Index/In-Wales-3/Sport-1` format?

Comment: Hi, No that is the aim to produce that url. The actual url is Find/Index?Region=Wales&rid=3&Interest=Sport&iid=1. Pretty ugly!!

Comment: Ah, I have used a similar thing once. Can you post the complete route map? I know the order in which the appear in code is really significant.

Comment: Hi Stefan, thanks for your input. I am aware that the routing function works on a FCFS basis in terms of pattern matching. The route setting is not the problem. The problem is how to submit the form to that URL. Using GET, which I dont know if there is a placeholder function for my drop down values. Or I could post and then perform a RedirectResult but this maybe inefficient. Cheers.

Comment: ..hmm now I see what you mean... And trying to figure it out as well :|

Answer (score 2):

For the PartialViews; it is the way to go if you re-use it on other pages. You can think of it a bit as 'encapsulated logic'.

**UPDATE:** Ignore the above if you are just using a partial view for a dropdownlist. There is a HtmlHelper, `Html.DropDownListFor()` for that.

For the first part; the order is relevant:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Pretty",
          url: "{controller}/{action}-{id}/Something",
          defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "Foo", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );

//default route
routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",  
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional    }
        );
```

for example will work if you would like to format the URL like:

```
http://local:23802/Test/Foo-5/Something
```